# Deconstruct type level list into nested tuple without sentinel for '[]

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to deconstruct a list of types (e.g. `'[Int, Int]`) into both a type and a way to create that type via type operators (isomorphic to nested tuples but nicer to write). For example:

```Haskell
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeInType #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, FlexibleInstances #-}

import Data.Kind (Type)

data a :<> b = a :<> b
infixr 8 :<>

class Construct a where
  type Result a :: Type

instance forall a as. (Show a, Construct as) => Construct (a:as) where
  type Result (a:as) = a :<> (Result as)

instance Construct '[] where
  type Result '[] = ()
```

When using this I get e.g.

```
λ  :kind! Result '[Int, Int, Int]
Result '[Int, Int, Int] :: *
= Int :<> (Int :<> (Int :<> ()))
```

Note the `:<> ()` at the end which I don't want. At first I tried matching more specifically on the length of the list elements, e.g. '[a, b]:

```Haskell
instance forall a b. (Show a, Show b) => Construct ('[a,b]) where
  type Result '[a,b] = a :<> b
```

But of course that doesn't work:

```
Conflicting family instance declarations:
  Result (a : as) = a :<> Result as -- Defined at test.hs:14:8
  Result '[a, b] = a :<> b -- Defined at test.hs:22:8
```

I can always construct up to N specific instances:

```Haskell
instance forall a. (Show a) => Construct '[a] where
  type Result '[a] = a

instance forall a b. (Show a, Show b) => Construct '[a,b] where
  type Result '[a, b] = a :<> b

instance forall a b c. (Show a, Show b, Show c) => Construct '[a,b,c] where
  type Result '[a, b, c] = a :<> b :<> c

-- etc. up to N
```

but that seems very unsatisfying.

Is there a way to unpack to `Int :<> (Int :<> Int)` instead of `Int :<> (Int :<> (Int :<> ())))` using the recursive definition?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use closed type families. They match top-to-bottom, so there's no conflict.

```
type family Construct (xs :: [Type]) :: Type where
  Construct '[x]      = x
  Construct (x ': xs) = x :<> Construct xs
```

Now `Construct [Int, Int, Int]` reduces to `Int :<> (Int :<> Int)`.

However, if I'm roughly right about how you intend to use this, you're much better off with heterogeneous lists, as they're easier to work with and have better type inference.

```
{-# language
  UndecidableInstances, RankNTypes, TypeOperators, TypeFamilies,
  TypeApplications, ScopedTypeVariables, GADTs, DataKinds, PolyKinds,
  ConstraintKinds, AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}

import Data.List
import Data.Kind

data HList (ts :: [Type]) :: Type where
  Nil  :: HList '[]
  (:>) :: t -> HList ts -> HList (t ': ts)
infixr 5 :>

-- example
foo :: HList [Int, String, Bool]  
foo = 0 :> "foo" :> True :> Nil
```

As an example for a useful operation on `HList`, if we know that each element type satisfies a class constraint, we can map over the list, either collecting it into a homogeneous list or preserving the element types:

```
type family AllC c (xs :: [a]) :: Constraint where
  AllC c '[]       = ()
  AllC c (x ': xs) = (c x, AllC c xs)

hmap :: forall c ts. AllC c ts => (forall x. c x => x -> x) -> HList ts -> HList ts
hmap f Nil       = Nil
hmap f (x :> xs) = f x :> hmap @c f xs

hmap' :: forall c ts r. AllC c ts => (forall x. c x => x -> r) -> HList ts -> [r]
hmap' f Nil       = []
hmap' f (x :> xs) = f x : hmap' @c f xs
```

We can use `TypeApplications` to set the `c` constraints. We can implement the `Show` instance for `HList` simply with the use of `hmap'`:

```
instance AllC Show ts => Show (HList ts) where
  show xs = "[" ++ intercalate ", " (hmap' @Show show xs) ++ "]"
```

Now we have in ghci:

```
> foo
[0, "foo", True]
```

which works because all element types of `foo` have `Show` instances.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know of an equivalent to closed type families for type classes? I.e. if I now want to write a matching function like `handler :: Result a -> Text` I seem I have the same unpack-sentinel issue, just moved to type classes.

Comment: @teh see edit for what should be a better solution (for what I think you'd like to do).